# Library for managing terminal app process

Tags: python-3.x, process, command-line-interface, tui

I'm creating a python terminal-based application that I'd like to start in the background (e.g. at boot time) and connect to using various terminal (bash) commands.  Is there an obvious package for this use-case?  Searching on google returns a number of potential candidates, but I'm unsure which tool (or another) is best suited for this use-case without extensive examination:

- pm2
- python-daemon
- flask
- python-service
- django
- argparse
- click
- supervisor
- celery
- ...

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by _connect to using various terminal (bash) commands_? Do want the daemon process to run certain bash commands?

Comment: @amanb I have in mind triggering a TUI event loop in the shell when a command is entered from terminal.  Just like argparse, but connecting to a running background process